# Dropwizard deserialize array

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

I am busy with a [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/) application and need to have an array injected to a POJO as one of the parameters of a `put` method. Unfortunately the array is not properly handled which results in a `Bad Request` response. To illustrate the JSON passed by the frontend looks like:

```
{
    "name": "Jon",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "children": ["Chris", "Dave", "Sam"]
}
```

And my Java representation:

```
public class Person{

  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private List<String> children;

  public Person(){

  }

  @JsonProperty
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }


  @JsonProperty
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
  }


  @JsonProperty
  public void setsurname(String surname){
    this.surname=surname;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public List<String> getChildren(){
    return children;
  }


  @JsonProperty
  public void setChildren(List<String> children){
    this.children=children;
  }

}
```

And in my resource class:

```
@PUT
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Path("/{userid}")
public Response getData(@PathParam("userid") LongParam userId,
                         Person person) {

    // Do some stuff with the person

}
```

How can I properly handle the deserialization of the array in the JSON?

**EDIT**

I am using an angular front-end and I am invoking the method as follows:

```
function(json){
            return  $http({
                url: API_URL.people+"/update/personID",
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json' 
                },
                data: json
            });
}
```

Where the `json` argument contains the name, surname and children as above.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the error you are getting?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no stacktrace from the server. Just a 400 Bad Request response when I try to access the path.

Comment: How are you trying to invoke the service? Are you using POSTMAN ?

Comment: I am invoking it with AJAX from my angular front-end.

Comment: How do you know it's the array causing the issue? My guess is it's something else. Have you tried [tracing](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#tracing) the request?

Comment: @spinlok I have made similar requests where the POJO classes don't have arrays or Lists which worked perfectly. Therefore I figured the problem is deserializing the array. I haven't tried tracing the request but I shall attempt it and report back as soon as possible.

Comment: You were right. The problem was with some other part of my code. I found a typo in my `javascript` when I created the `json` to pass to the `PUT` method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code I provided words like a charm. Upon further investigation I made a mistake in the `javascript` object which got converted and sent as `JSON` which caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the GET service is defined incorrectly. It shouldn't have `Person` defined.

As per `http` method definition, the `GET http method` can't have body. So you can't have `Person` as the input parameter.

If you need to send `Person` to service, you may need to change the http method to POST or something else (like `PUT`) based on your requirement.

```
@GET
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Path("/{userid}")
public Response getData(@PathParam("userid") LongParam userId) {

    // Do some stuff with the person

}
```

Comment: My apologies, it should be a Put method. I edited the question accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.